# pub get failed command: "C:\scr\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory ..\..\scr\flutter\packages\flutter_tools get

Tags: flutter

```
[pub get failed command: "C:\scr\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory ..\..\scr\flutter\packages\flutter_tools get --example" pub env: {   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\scr\flutter",   "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get", } exit code: 69]
```

This error is thrown when I'm trying to install flutter for the first time on windows 11, as you see in the screenshot below. This also shows the error after running the flutter doctor command.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to repair pub cache:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Restart your app.